# Font Awesome icons doesn't load

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I tried to load the Font Awesome 5 script, but the icons doesn't load. The console doesn't say anything, so I don't know what there happens.

All of my inserted icons changes to a strange sign:
[Strange sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLUeh.png)

This is my code from Font Awesome:
`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4d7903326f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

And here I'm loading in the icons:
`<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>`

I'm programming in PHP, so I can't show the full code.

Who can help me? Thank you!

Comment: You should download styles from [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) and host them localy instead using external link. Follow instructions

Comment: Even if you are coding in PHP you can still show the HTML which is all that matters to troubleshoot this.